# Set state not being executed corretly.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have two components, where a user can attach an image or gif to a post. Whenever the image is clicked, a modal pop up, and I want to pass the data, back to modal, so the clicked image shows.

I have made a lifecycle hook so that I can check if props are being sent, and then set the state in my child component like such:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(){
if(this.props.modalImageData){
  this.setState({imageData: this.props.modalImageData})
 }
}
```

this works fine, but I'm having issues passing the state correctly.

I made a handler, where I'm passing the image data, of the clicked image into a handler, that is setting the state, for a property called imageModalData, which I'm passing to the CreateGif component:

```
 showModalSpeceficHandler = (event, image) =>{
    //console.log(event.target.value);
    console.log('image data is ' + image)
    this.setState({imageModalData: image})
    console.log('modal image data is ' + 
    this.state.imageModalData)
    this.showModalHandler()
}
```

Here I'm experiencing issues when I first console log the image, that is being passed into the function, it is correct, but afterward, when I console log the state, of the imageModalData It's displaying a random picture.

afterward, the random picture is passed back down to the child component, which is not desired, what am I doing wrong since the state is not sat correctly

```
Modal show={this.state.showModal} modalClosed={this.showModalHandler}>
                <CreateGif onSelectUrl={this.addedImageHandler} onSelectFile={this.addFileDataHandler} modalImageData={this.state.imageModalData}/* this is where the data is passed back down */  />
```

Comment: Firstly in componentWillRecieveProps you will recieve newProps, you have to check against that, you need to modifiy the function as componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
if(newProps.modalImageData){
  this.setState({imageData: newProps.modalImageData})
 }
}

Comment: The `setState` is an asynchronous function. When you `console.log` it, the state may not be updated already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [docs for `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.

If you need to ensure that the update has been applied before some action is fired (like rendering your modal), you can use the `setState(updater, callback)` form:

```
this.setState(
  // updater function, returning a state update
  state => ({imageModalData: image}),
  // callback function, executed after update is applied
  () => this.showModalHandler()
);
```

Comment: This is brillant! Thank you